# Automating GPG in bash

Tags: bash, xorg, gnupg, automation

I'd like to make a script that automates GPG *1.4.20* using a user-given password, and it will be operating on a *lot* of files, so naturally, I'd like to automate giving it a password. However, no matter what I do, it always opens an X pop-up asking for the password. I've tried using `--passphrase` and `--passphrase-fd 0` with a pipe to no avail, it still asks using the pop-up. Is there some way to avoid the pop-up?

Comment: try [how to use gnupgs passphrase-fd argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19895122/how-to-use-gnupgs-passphrase-fd-argument) or [gpg asks for password even with --passphrase](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/60439/98672)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I was using GPG 1.4.20 (sorry about forgetting that), the only thing that would work for me was the combined use of `--batch` and `--no-use-agent`. I'm assuming it was the agent running that produced the popup.